# Connecting with server using smack API in MainActivity android

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I am trying to receive and send messages using Smack API but not been able to do it in a separate class due to some threads issue may be. But when now i ported all the code in MainActivity i wont be able to make a connection with server.Below is my MainActivity.class.

```
public class chatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String DOMAIN = "192.168.0.109";
    private static final String HOST = "192.168.0.109";
    private static final int PORT = 5222;
    private String userName ="";
    private String passWord = "";
    AbstractXMPPConnection connection ;
    ChatManager chatmanager ;
    Chat newChat;
    ChatManager chatManager;
    XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
    private boolean connected;
    private boolean isToasted;
    private boolean chat_created;
    private boolean loggedin;
    Context context;
    private MultiUserChat multiUserChat;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                init("user123","user123");
            }
        });
t.start();

    }

    public void init(String userId,String pwd ) {
        Log.i("XMPP", "Initializing!");
        this.userName = userId;
        this.passWord = pwd;
        this.context = context;
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(userName, passWord);
        configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        configBuilder.setResource("Android");
        configBuilder.setServiceName(DOMAIN);
        configBuilder.setHost(HOST);
        configBuilder.setPort(PORT);
        //configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
        connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);

    }
    public class XMPPConnectionListener implements ConnectionListener {
        @Override
        public void connected(final XMPPConnection connection) {

            Log.d("xmpp", "Connected!");
            connected = true;


            if (!connection.isAuthenticated()) {
                System.out.println("Hellooooooooo11111");
                login();

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
//                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//new MainActivity().updateText(context);

                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosed() {
            if (isToasted)

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    }
                });
            Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionCLosed!");
            connected = false;
            chat_created = false;
            loggedin = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0) {
            if (isToasted)

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
            Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionClosedOn Error!");
            connected = false;

            chat_created = false;
            loggedin = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectingIn(int arg0) {

            Log.d("xmpp", "Reconnectingin " + arg0);

            loggedin = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0) {
            if (isToasted)

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {



                    }
                });
            Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionFailed!");
            connected = false;

            chat_created = false;
            loggedin = false;
        }


        @Override
        public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
            if (isToasted)

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    }
                });
            Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionSuccessful");
            connected = true;

            chat_created = false;
            loggedin = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticated(XMPPConnection arg0, boolean arg1) {
            Log.d("xmpp", "Authenticated!");
            loggedin = true;
            //  joinChatRoom();
            //  sendMsg();
            chat_created = false;
            //sendMessage("body","jid");
            //sendMsg();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        //   sendMsg();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).start();
            if (isToasted)

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    }
                });
        }
    }
    public void login() {

        try {
            connection.login(userName, passWord);
            //  sendMsg();
            //Log.i("LOGIN", "Yey! We're connected to the Xmpp server!");

        } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}
```

My **Question** is how can I use smack API, I am not getting it at all that how to handle this network operations in main class.
I did try to run it in Asynch too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution i forgot to add the following method in my main class.

```
public void connectConnection()
    {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectionThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                // Create a connection
                try {
                    connection.connect();
                    login();
                    connected = true;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                } catch (SmackException e) {

                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                }

                return null;
            }
        };
        connectionThread.execute();
    }
```